# As a beginner mobile developer, I need some guidance

Tags: android, ios, mobile, xamarin

I need input on my research so far on paths for mobile development

With job availability being the priority, so far I see 2 reasonable options (I'll add my take on both so far)

1. Xamarin/Xamarin.Forms development

I feel like this cross-platform development technology is still very young, and therefore risky to invest time in, as it could easily die out.
Also, the Xamarin.Forms cross-platform UI development platform seems like it is unstable.

2. Android/iOS native development

Seems to have alot more support online. Is more of a secure option for jobs at the moment, though Xamarin is quickly growing popularity as more and more companies move towards x-plat dev.

Is this accurate? Any input would be greatly appreciated as the answer will influence my future

Thanks

Comment: While it is a good question, I believe it would be better suited to be asked in Meta-Stack as this question is asking for an opinion about your own personal opinion/questions relating to programming rather than an actual programming question. Thought I would make the comment in case anyone decides to downvote or flag your question to `close` for the reason that it is "primarily opinion-based or is not about programming as described in the help center, and it is unlikely to be fixed via editing."

Comment: There are more Xamarin jobs than there are qualified developers. Learn all 3 mobile platforms and you will not have trouble finding work. I wouldn't restrict myself to Xamarin.Forms but it's an easy path to learn the mobile platforms and from there you can proceed to Xamarin.iOS, Xamarin.Android & also Windows Phone development to get a deeper knowledge of each platform. Master one, with or without Xamarin, and you will find work. Master two and you will be in extremely high demand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Heh ...* "And just how long, Young Turk, do you imagine 'your future' to *be?"*

In other words:  "how many *decades?"*  (Answer: "about five.")

Are you even thinking in terms of *"decades?"*  (Answer: "obviously not.")

**:-)**

Let me, therefore, give you this marvelous bit of good news ... (from a point-of-view of *nearly four .. ahem* decades):

> You can *never* predict [a company's] future.
>
> All you can ever hope to do ... is to satisfy their client's business needs, *today.*

I have *(believe it or not)* been making money in this business since *before* there was (uhh....) "a PC."  Therefore, of this statement I feel I can be *quite* sure . . .

> "Your statement," Young Turk, "is 'most *temporal.'*"  (In other words: "even *next year,* it probably won't be relevant.")  Therefore, I cordially suggest that you "instead, take the *long* view."

**Assume** that it is, in fact, *impossible(!)* to predict "how the chips of present-day technology may fall," *knowing that(!!!!),* in the long view, "it absolutely doesn't matter anyway."

The companies who need to hire you "have made their bets."  Only time will tell whether their bets were the right ones. *(Hell, they don't know, either.)* Meanwhile: *they need you, and meanwhile, they have Money.*  You don't have to "pick the winning horse."  You only have to find people who have, *today,* "gambled upon *this* horse."

"**Two** years hence, none of this will matter anyway."  *(Seriously.  "Welcome to The Business.")*

---

**P.S.:** "Don't be afraid."  It is precisely this very aspect of "the software development business" that first captivated me, all those years ago, and that *still* engages me, today.

Comment: Awesome answer, I will take your advice and develop in what is big today, and if Xamarin grows, I will move over. Thank you for your generous and knowledgeable advice.

Comment: My comment, rather, was meant to say:  "What is 'big today'" might or might not be "big" tomorrow.  *(But,* it will still "be around!")  You can't anticipate these things.  Simply choose one thing (at a time) to study, but always, *always,* understand that anything which you study "has a relatively short shelf-life."  You will *always* be confronted with yet-another job requirement that "for a little while, will have you 'scrambling to catch up.'"  But you know to expect it.  You know that you *can.*  (And, by the way, so does your boss.  That's *why* they hire you.)  Welcome to the business!!

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help. Your experience is invaluable for someone in my position in life.

Comment: Happy to, Joshua.  "Been there, done that."  (And, in a certain real sense, *still* there.)